# Difference in behaviour of ClipRRect border radius property on specifying height to parent widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have raised an issue on github for the ClipRRect border radius. Could someone help me out?

Issue URL

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/93589

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused because the image stays at the same size. Maybe trying to use `fit` should work.

```
Image.network(
   'https://flutter-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/sample_img.png',
    width: 250,
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
 ),
```

You can also do it like this its a bit cleaner maybe

```
Container(
  height: 100.0,
  width: 100.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50), 
    //set border radius to 50% of square height and width
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage("assets/img.png"),
      fit: BoxFit.cover, //change image fill type
    ),
  ),
 )
```

Comment: If this solved the problem please mark it as answered to indicate its working for other people